# Spring security login fail wrong redirect and no error message

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to build a simple login form (JS) and to user Spring security. As far as I understood, when login fails, it should redirect to login page (or is that only for JSP login pages inside bootstrap project?) but it fails do to that. 
And query Error string parameter is also empty.

My spring security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        // ensure the passwords are encoded properly
        User.UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(users.username("user").password("user").roles("USER").build());
        manager.createUser(users.username("admin").password("admin").roles("USER","ADMIN").build());
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

From JS app I am sending a request to `http://localhost:8080/login`, I don't think it matters in this case, but I'm using MithrilJS request:

```
m.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
    body: {username: login, password: pass}
})
.then((result) => {
    UserLogin.loggedIn = true;
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Responses (2 for some reason) I get:

```
http://localhost:8080/login?error 
Request Method: OPTIONS
Response is empty
error string is also empty

http://localhost:8080/login?error 
Request Method: GET
error String is empty
```

And now the funny part, response contains html **(note that I don't have this HTML anywhere in my code)**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Please sign in</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/login">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Invalid credentials</div>        <p>
          <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
</body></html>
```

Any ideas where am I failing?

**EDIT:**

Thank your for the answers, while it did not answer exactly what I had in mind, it did lead me to right direction.

My main problem was that I have 2 separate projects: 1) a spring boot project 2) a JS application. JS application contains form html itself (or JS in this case) since I don't want any front end code to be or come from backend (spring boot project) while all the login logic is in spring boot spring security.

If I disable formLogin (which I have to do, no to use spring login form) I get no /login endpoint.

To summarize, I want to use spring security while bypassing spring login form (this way backend contains login logic, which can be accessed by any form, or that is the idea).

While I'm not quite there yet, I'm getting there.

For anyone that's curious, this is the article that helped: [spring security without login form](https://insource.io/blog/articles/custom-authentication-with-spring-boot.html)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do authentication with ajax, so you can not redirect to any other page dependent on server response, you should do that in you JS(e.g. `window.location.href`).

Now let's talk about the `form login` in your case.  The `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is enabled based on your configuration.

```
.formLogin()
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
    .permitAll()
```

This filter will get username and password from the request params.

```
protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getParameter(usernameParameter);
}
protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getParameter(passwordParameter);
}
```

But you are trying to send a json body to the server, so it can not get the right credential. You should change it to a `form` request.

Next one is about the fail redirect url, now you should know the ajax can not redirect to an other page, the default `failureHandler` in you configuration will redirect to the login page with error, now you are using ajax, so you just can get the HTML, I think you can just validate the request based on the header(e.g. 401), here is an example.

```
.formLogin()
    .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
```

Here is the code in `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`

```
if (defaultFailureUrl == null) {
    logger.debug("No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error");
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(),
                HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
}
```

You can get the result based on the header and the body.

Now I think your should know the `defaultSuccessUrl` in your configuration will not work as you expect. You need to implement you own `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

The last one is about your `form` authentication, the form authentication most of it is based on cookie, I think all your requests should contains the cookie to the server after login successfully. Maybe you can research [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/) to instead.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is the default login form.

Why did you define formLogin()?

You must send username and password in the Authorization header not in the body.

From https://mithril.js.org/request.html

```
m.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
    user: login, 
    password: pass
})
.then((result) => {
    UserLogin.loggedIn = true;
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```